# How to get the only key-value pair in a Map object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

The language is TypeScript / JavaScript on NodeJS. I have a map that occasionally has only one key. When that is the case, I need to get both the key and the object mapped to it and do some processing with it. The function that is responsible for processing the map doesn't know the what the value of the key is. Therefore, I cannot call `get()` passing in the key.

Just to clarify the map is an actual `Map` object.

My question is: How can I retrieve the key and its mapped value when there is only one key in the map and its value is unknown? I'd like to use the `entries()` method, but it returns an iterator.

```js
if (map.size === 1) {
    let key
    let value
    // how do I populate key and value? 
}
```

Comment: @Abion47 - ever tried that? `Object.entries` doesn't work that way on a map.

Comment: If you don't like using the iterator, convert it to an array with the spread operator: `[...map.entries()]`

Answer (score 3):

Invoking the iterator manually with `.next` and taking the two resulting values from the array works:

```js
const map = new Map([['foo', 'bar']]);
const [key, value] = map.entries().next().value;
console.log(key, value);
```

Comment: Or, if you don't want to mess with the iterator: `const [[key, value], ...rest] = [...map.entries()];`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```js
if (map.size === 1) {
    let keyValuePair = map.entries().next().value; // get next element in generator and it's value
    let key = keyValuePair[0];
    let value = keyValuePair[1];
    // do whatever you want
}
```

Or if you want a shorter syntax:

```js
if (map.size === 1) {
    let [key, value] = map.entries().next().value;
    // do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `for... of...` structure:

```
for (var [mapKey, mapValue] of map) {
  key = mapKey;
  value = mapValue;
}
```

Even if it's only one key, this way you can access it even without knowing what key it is.

The same can be done with the `forEach()` method...